# Growing documents vs inserting new ones

Tags: mongodb, database-design

Assume I need to design a data model where I store address changes of persons. I can think of two ways to implement it: updating the person's document or, inserting a new document representing the change.

With the update approach, each person has one document which includes an array of addresses and an address is added to the array when the person's address changes.

With the insert approach, there may be multiple documents per person. Each document represents the address change of the concerned person.

Assume the only person information stored in the documents is the person's unique identifier and the addresses. I precise it so that data duplication with the insert approach is considered negligible.

Which approach is recommended when MongoDB is used as database?

Comment: Which approach suits you? Really the whole concept of "embedding" is largely aimed at if you want to use "most of the data most of the time" and conversely linking is that you want to use a "subset of the data most of the time". The other basic constraint is "size", as growing arrays to unreasoble proportions ( even if under 16MB BSON limit ) is not good for performance. So it's really about "how you use it" and not a general recommendation or "way of doing things". Do what suits you best. Without clarification on usage, no answer can really tell you what to choose.

Answer (score 0):

Design of your Data Model should be finalized based on your application need.

The following points need to be taken care while choosing between updating the existing document or inserting a new document

Updating the existing Document

Pros:

- Retrieval of address is lot easier

Cons:

- The size of the document may exceed 16MB. MongoDB supports document upto 16MB data limit.

Inserting a New Document

Pros:

- Retrieval of Address is based only on the person's unique identifier
- The size of the document will be always under 16MB

Cons:

- We will end up in creating documents for each and every address change
- Query to retrieve the Person details with address will be complicated

I would recommend to go for Updating the Existing Document assuming that it wont exceed the data limit.